# Magento Content below the Page

Tags: magento, block

I am having trouble with Magento CE 1.7.0.2 displaying content of my custom block below the page. The block displays right on the page, but the content is copied below the page after the closing HTML tag.
The display layout plugin only shows my block referenced once, so I have no idea why this is happening. I'm using a default/custom package. Please help!!!!

My Layout, if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <remove name="store_language" />
        <remove name="store_switcher"/>
        <remove name="footer_links" />
    </default>
    <makeorder_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="makeorder/orderblock" output="toHtml" name="orderdispaly"
                    template="makeorder/orderdisplay.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </makeorder_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove the `output="toHtml"` directive from your "makeorder/orderblock" block properties. What this does is basically says to display the contents of your block as soon as it's initialized - no matter where it should be placed. So it ends up rendered after the "root" block.